# error with read .pem file?

Tags: java, jsch

Here is my code:

```
public class ConnectToDB {

private static final URL PEM_FILE_DIR = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("line_scrapper.pem");

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ConnectToDB.class);

private static void doSshTunnel(String strSshUser, String strSshPassword, String strSshHost, int nSshPort,
        String strRemoteHost, int nLocalPort, int nRemotePort) throws JSchException, IOException,
        URISyntaxException {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    jsch.addIdentity(PEM_FILE_DIR.getPath());
    Session session = jsch.getSession(strSshUser, strSshHost, 22);
    session.setPassword(strSshPassword);

    final Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);

    session.connect();
    session.setPortForwardingL(nLocalPort, strRemoteHost, nRemotePort);
}

public static void ssh() {
    try {
        // System.out.println("start");
        String strSshUser = "ec2-user"; // SSH loging username
        String strSshPassword = "smartbites"; // SSH login password
        String strSshHost = "54.204.144.132"; // hostname or ip or SSH
                                                // server
        int nSshPort = 22; // remote SSH host port number
        String strRemoteHost = "127.0.0.1"; // hostname or ip of your
                                            // database server
        int nLocalPort = 3366; // local port number use to bind SSH tunnel
        int nRemotePort = 3306; // remote port number of your database
        String strDbUser = "root"; // database loging username
        String strDbPassword = "smartbites"; // database login password

        ConnectToDB.doSshTunnel(strSshUser, strSshPassword, strSshHost, nSshPort, strRemoteHost, nLocalPort,
                nRemotePort);

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:" + nLocalPort
                + "/okpanda_teachers_accounts", strDbUser, strDbPassword);
        con.prepareCall("");
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("error ", e);

    }
    // finally
    // {
    // System.exit(0);
    // }
}
```

}

I would like to connect to the DB (not local but which is on the server) and store data, for test i create such test class and run it:

```
public class HrantTest {


    //  public static void main(String[] args) {
//      test();

//  }

public static void test() {

    ReadingFromTxtFile file = new ReadingFromTxtFile(new File("C:\\Users\\Hrant\\Desktop\\line"), "GMT-8:00");
    ConnectToDB.ssh();
    file.writeForAllFiles();

}
```

}

my line_scrapper.pem file is in rescources folder(it's maven project). So i run it and it connect to DB and store data in DB.
But after build . jar file, I run it and throws exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\Hrant\GitRepos\LineScraper\LineMessangerScraper\target\LineMessangerScraper-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!\line_scrapper.pem (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:525)
at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:393)
at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:353)
at com.hrant.ConnectToDB.doSshTunnel(ConnectToDB.java:30)
at com.hrant.ConnectToDB.ssh(ConnectToDB.java:57)
at com.hrant.HrantTest.test(HrantTest.java:16)
at com.hrant.gui.LineFrame$3.run(LineFrame.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\Hrant\GitRepos\LineScraper\LineMessangerScraper\target\LineMessangerScraper-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!\line_scrapper.pem (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.fromFile(Util.java:508)
at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:522)
... 12 more
```

So i dont understand problem with reading .pem file or with

```
jsch.addIdentity(PEM_FILE_DIR.getPath());
```

so how solve this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSch#addIdentity(String)` [expects the name of a file on the filesystem](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#addIdentity%28java.lang.String%29), which you don't have when it's packed into a jar; presumably, the reasoning is that the identity information (private key) is sensitive and shouldn't be included in the jar but should be externalized.

If there's an overwhelmingly compelling reason to override this, you'll need to use the overload that has you pass in the keys as byte arrays instead. You might also consider opening a bug against JSch to make the PEM reader available with an `InputStream` or `Reader`.